# Backtesting a simple HA momentum strategy on TradingView

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, tradingview-api

I'm trying to backtest a simple heikin ashi movement strategy on tradingview using pinescript. So as per my knowledge, on uptrend the open price of heikin ashi candle always increases and on downtrend it decreases...

So I wrote this simple script,

```
//@version=5
strategy("Simple Heikin Ashi")

ha_open = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open)
ha_high = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high)
ha_low = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low)
ha_close = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)

price = ha_close


long_condition =  ha_open[1]>ha_open[2] and ha_open[2]<ha_open[3]
close_condition =   ha_open[1]<ha_open[2] and ha_open[2]>ha_open[3]

if (long_condition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
 
if (close_condition)
    strategy.close("long")
```

I used the price data of two previous candle [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P50KN.png) & [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aVIU.png) to avoid repainting. But the entry positons on my chart are so random. And when I try to add it as alert, it shows this strategy repaints.

How can it repaint when I'm using previous candle data...

Also here are the screenshots of chart,

Heikin Ashi Candle
[image: Heikin Ashi Candle]

Normal Candle
[image: Normal Candle]

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
strategy("Simple Heikin Ashi")

ha_open = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open)
ha_high = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high)
ha_low = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low)
ha_close = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)

price = ha_close

long_condition =false
short_condition =false
if barstate.isconfirmed
    long_condition =  ha_open[1]>ha_open[2] and ha_open[2]<ha_open[3]
if barstate.isconfirmed
    close_condition =   ha_open[1]<ha_open[2] and 
    ha_open[2]>ha_open[3]

if (long_condition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
 
if (close_condition)
    strategy.close("long")
```

try that - but overall would not suggest using HA since there is a price difference from HA to Normal candles and alerts work on normal candles you would then get it at the price of the normal candles not where it shows on HA.